# [ios] matches Cisco's IOS and Apple's iOS

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tags

Apple had the wonderful idea to name its mobile operating system iOS, which was already used by Cisco Internet Operating System.

There are hence [94 questions tagged](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ios) [ios](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ios), but [only 82 of them](https://serverfault.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D%20cisco) contain also the word "cisco".

We could create a new tag, [apple-ios](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apple-ios), and move the existing [ios](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ios) to [cisco-ios](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cisco-ios).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMHO Apple iOS devices are ***OFF TOPIC*** and should be closed/migrated to the correct site. I can get on board with [cisco-ios](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cisco-ios) since that is more specific, and then alias [ios](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ios)->[cisco-ios](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cisco-ios).

Comment: well, as iDevices are specific platforms, they _may_ be related to server administration...

Comment: Indeed! We have both apple.se and SuperUser for targets for those.

Comment: I am not sure they are always off topic. I.e. an enterprise rollout of iPhones as Exchange clients would likely be on topic.

Comment: If it is an enterprise rollout, [ios] wouldn't really be a good tag IMO. [iphone] and [ipad] do exist, but I'd only not close them unless it was absolutely clear this was for an enterprise deployment.